# Query taking too much time (3 mins for 100k records)

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

Query below with explain plan taking 3+ minutes, please suggest how I can reduce the time:
Select statement and count(*) both are taking same time.

```
SELECT
     s.sap_id AS 'SAP ID', 
     z.name AS 'Circle' , 
     m.mme_host_name AS 'MME HostName',  
     case when mmelog.retry_count is null then  m.mme_status  when mmelog.retry_count is not null then  mmelog.status else null end AS 'Status',   
     case when mmelog.retry_count is null then m.description   when mmelog.retry_count is not null then mmelog.reason   else null end AS 'Description'  , 
     m.modifiedTime AS Date, 
     ifnull(mmelog.retry_count,0)as 'Retry Count'
FROM
    site s
INNER JOIN zone z ON s.zone_id = z.id
INNER JOIN mme_result m ON m.site_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN mme_connection_log mmelog ON mmelog.sap_id = s.sap_id
WHERE
    m.modifiedTime >= '2015-07-25'
AND m.modifiedTime <= '2016-07-25'
ORDER BY
    m.modifiedTime,
    s.sap_id;
```

Below it the Explain plan:

```
----+-------------+--------+-------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys                        | key                 | key_len | ref            | rows  | Extra                                                           |
    +----+-------------+--------+-------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | z      | index | PRIMARY                              | creator             | 5       | NULL           |    24 | Using index                                                     |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | s      | ref   | PRIMARY,site_region_fk               | site_region_fk      | 5       | siteforge.z.id |  1915 | NULL                                                            |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | m      | ref   | FK89FCE6D7459A62FF,modifiedTimeIndex | FK89FCE6D7459A62FF  | 5       | siteforge.s.id |     2 | Using where                                                     |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | mmelog | index | NULL                                 | idx_sapid_mmeconlog | 258     | NULL           | 16616 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
    +----+-------------+--------+-------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------+-------+---
```

| mme_connection_log |

```
CREATE TABLE `mme_connection_log` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mme_host_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modifiedTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `retry_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sap_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `creator` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modifier` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sap_id` (`sap_id`,`mme_host_name`),
  KEY `FKAD24771D82DD582F` (`creator`),
  KEY `FKAD24771D43DE0263` (`last_modifier`),
  KEY `mmehostINdex` (`mme_host_name`),
  KEY `idx_sapid_mmeconlog` (`sap_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKAD24771D43DE0263` FOREIGN KEY (`last_modifier`) REFERENCES `users` (`userid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKAD24771D82DD582F` FOREIGN KEY (`creator`) REFERENCES `users` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=55047 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

| mme_result |

```
CREATE TABLE `mme_result` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mme_host_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mme_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modifiedTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `zone_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mme_host_name` (`mme_host_name`,`site_id`),
  KEY `FK89FCE6D7C1D1CCDF` (`zone_id`),
  KEY `FK89FCE6D7459A62FF` (`site_id`),
  KEY `mmehostINdex` (`mme_host_name`),
  KEY `modifiedTimeIndex` (`modifiedTime`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK89FCE6D7459A62FF` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `site` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK89FCE6D7C1D1CCDF` FOREIGN KEY (`zone_id`) REFERENCES `zone` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=914671 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

SAPID is not distinct

Comment: use explain to find out whare you Need an index.

Comment: By the way makes `Count(*)` without `Group by` sence?

Comment: Add the explain result to your question, not as comment

Comment: Size and indices of tables perhaps?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` output for all tables involved in your query.

Comment: order by has no sense here

Comment: Aside from all you provided in your question, can you put in simple English what you want... ex: For each "Result" record, I want the total connection log entries.  I want the results grouped by each site...  Also, do you want DISTINCT Count of Sites, count of all, ignore grouping because you just want a count for everything that happened over the year?  This is why you have no answer yet to your post.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE site` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE zone` as well. Joining on a `VARCHAR(255)` for `sap_id` certainly explains some of the slowness here.

Answer (score 1):

When you have `UNIQUE(a,b)`, you don't need `KEY(a)`.  Each of those tables has one such redundant index.

If you remove `zone` from the query, do you get the right answer?  It seems to be only saying "we must have a zone entry".

`m` may benefit from `INDEX(site_id, modifiedTime)` (in that order).

Most columns are `NULL`.  Those that will never be set to `NULL` should be declared `NOT NULL`.

Don't blindly say `varchar(255)`, especially for keys.  See if you can make them smaller (without risking overflow).

`LEFT JOIN` with `COUNT(*)` seems strange.  It implies you are counting missing rows in the 'right' table; can you justtify `LEFT`?

Could you show us the other two tables; there may be further suggestions.